# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file tested on localhost (wordpress theme)

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing, localhost

i'm trying to create a wordpress theme from scratch and then test it on localhost. this code is from front-page.php

i keep getting this error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\wamp\www\director\front-page.php on line 56`

( line 56 is the last line of the code)

with this code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
    $posts= get_posts(array('numberposts' => 4,'category' => 3, orderby => 'title'));
    foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
?>

<?php
    $args= array('post_type' => 'businesses', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' => 'business-type', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'featured')));

    $featuredBusiness=get_posts($args);
        foreach ($featuredBusiness as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
?>

    <div id="featured" class="group">
    <div class="business-info right-col">
        <hr/>
        <h3>Featured Business:</h3>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="impact-image">
        <?php print get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'storefront'); ?>
    </div>
    </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <div id="main" class="group">
        <div id="posts" class="left-col">

            <?php
                $posts= get_posts('posts_per_page=3');
                foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

            <div class="post group">
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <div class="byline">by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
                        on <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_time('l F d, Y'); ?></a>
                    </div>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            </div>

            <?php
                $blogID=get_page_by_path('blog');
                $blogLink=get_page_link($blogID->ID);
            ?>
            <a class="visit" href=" <?php print $blogLink; ?>">Visit the Blog</a>

        </div>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

i checked but i don't seem to be missing any closing tags or something. is there something i'm missing or not seeing?

Comment: Can you post the `get_footer()` function?

Comment: You've missed to end your last `foreach` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just close your last foreach loop ...

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
    $posts= get_posts(array('numberposts' => 4,'category' => 3, orderby => 'title'));
    foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
?>

<?php
    $args= array('post_type' => 'businesses', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' => 'business-type', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'featured')));

    $featuredBusiness=get_posts($args);
        foreach ($featuredBusiness as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
?>

    <div id="featured" class="group">
    <div class="business-info right-col">
        <hr/>
        <h3>Featured Business:</h3>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="impact-image">
        <?php print get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'storefront'); ?>
    </div>
    </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <div id="main" class="group">
        <div id="posts" class="left-col">

            <?php
                $posts= get_posts('posts_per_page=3');
                foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

            <div class="post group">
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <div class="byline">by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
                        on <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_time('l F d, Y'); ?></a>
                    </div>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            </div>

            <?php
                $blogID=get_page_by_path('blog');
                $blogLink=get_page_link($blogID->ID);
            ?>
            <a class="visit" href=" <?php print $blogLink; ?>">Visit the Blog</a>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```